# React native development server returned response error code :500

Tags: react-native, react-android

The application is installed in the emulator. But it is not starting. Emulator points me out [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Ka2.jpg) error.

At the same time server gives following errors.

> error: bundling failed: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'throwIfClosureRequired' of undefined (While processing preset:
>   "C:\Users\sajithk\UTransP\node_modules\babel-preset-react-native\index.js")
>       at _default (C:\Users\sajithk\UTransP\node_modules\babel-preset-react-native\node_modules\@babel\plugin-transform-block-scoping\lib\index.js:19:36)
>       at Function.memoisePluginContainer (C:\Users\sajithk\UTransP\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:113:13)
>       at Function.normalisePlugin (C:\Users\sajithk\UTransP\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:146:32)
>       at C:\Users\sajithk\UTransP\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:184:30
>       at Array.map ()
>       at Function.normalisePlugins (C:\Users\sajithk\UTransP\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:158:20)
>       at OptionManager.mergeOptions (C:\Users\sajithk\UTransP\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:234:36)
>       at C:\Users\sajithk\UTransP\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:265:14
>       at C:\Users\sajithk\UTransP\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:323:22
>   BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.

This is the first time i ran the application in the emulator after creating the project.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and in my case I solved it by changing the babel-preset-react-native version from 5.0.0 to 4.0.0

And follow the instructions:

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.

Answer (score 0):

What's your `babel-preset-react-native` version?

Try this command:

```
npm install --save babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

in console: `npx react-native start`

Answer (score -2):

```
npm install react-navigation --save
```

I used the above fixed my issue, if anyone have same issue, just try.
if anyone know why this command can fix  the issue, I am happy to learn.
Cheers